# How to paging gridView

Tags: asp.net

I have grid view with this :

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridViewCosts" runat="server"   CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" ShowFooter="True" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDeleting="GridViewCosts_RowDeleting" Width="387px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridViewCosts_SelectedIndexChanged" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" 
PageSize="5" >
```

but this give in me error: `The data source does not support server-side data paging.`

in code behind i have something like this :

```
GridViewCosts.DataSource = rdr;
Line 55:                    GridViewCosts.DataBind();
```

how to paging my gridView which isn't have dataSource

**UPDATE**
I modify I have this

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridViewCosts" runat="server"   CellPadding="4" 
        ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" ShowFooter="True" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True"
         AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDeleting="GridViewCosts_RowDeleting" Width="387px"
         OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridViewCosts_SelectedIndexChanged" 
         OnPageIndexChanging="GridViewCosts_PageIndexChanging"

        PageSize="5" >
```

in code Behind have this :

```
  public void getViewProfit()
        {
            string connectionString = cs.getConnection();
            string query = "select Id ,name,value,Description,DateCreate from AllCostView where IdUser = '" + cui.getCurrentId() + "'";
            using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                myConnection.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
                using (SqlDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                   GridViewCosts.DataSource = rdr;
                   GridViewCosts.DataBind();
                }

            }
        }

  protected void GridViewCosts_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewCosts.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            getViewProfit();
        }
```

there no error any more , but  still not show paging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used datareader?yes,Please use DataSet/DataTable instead since a Datareader. Because  Datareader doesn't support paging and sorting capability, the DataReader retrieves a ReadOnly , ForwardOnly stream of data from database..

And you missed the gridview's pageindexChanging property,

for see below

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewCosts" runat="server"   CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" ShowFooter="True" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDeleting="GridViewCosts_RowDeleting" Width="387px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridViewCosts_SelectedIndexChanged" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" 
PageSize="5" **OnPageIndexChanging="GridViewCosts_PageIndexChanging"**>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void GridViewCosts1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewCosts.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

    //rebind your gridview .    

}
```

Comment: i Update my question please see it

Comment: Are you bind gridview inside of !IsPostBack in page loage for
void page-load()
{
if(!IsPostBack)
getViewProfit();
}
}